# How to customize a method arguments in Xcode autocomplete

Tags: xcode

The header for NSDictionary shows one thing.

```
- (void)enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:(void (^)(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop))block NS_AVAILABLE(10_6, 4_0);
```

When you start typing the method, Xcode's autocomplete expands it to something else

```
[dictionary enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
}]
```

Does anyone know how to customize what Xcode autocomplete fills in for a method argument?

Comment: Have you thought about creating a code snippet with the same code?

Comment: Yeah, I was going to fall back on that. I was hoping to avoid having to create snippets for this type of thing.

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, but where exactly do you see a difference in the arguments?

Comment: There is no difference in args. When it is expanded, instead of just expanding to [dictionary enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock: id key, id obj, BOOL *stop] it converts it to the right form of block syntax. I'm sure this is because of the block syntax that is already there as the arg. It's just curious that block args get expanded to a different format. Whereas most other args it's what you see is what you get.